# Covariance of $X$ and $Y$ is 0

Tags: probability, statistics, covariance, correlation

Let $X$ be a random variable. Is it possible to construct a random variable $Y=g(X)$, with $g$ strictly monotone, such that $\text{cov}(X,Y)=0$?

Comment: Are you considering $X$ a continuous or discrete random variable? or it doesn't matter? Some months ago I  thought about a similar question for some time https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460802/which-f-satisfies-efx-x-efx-ex for discrete variables and I am under the impression that only a constant $g(\cdot)$ satisfies the requirement. It was true for every specific distribution of $X$ I played with, but I didn't prove it in the general setting.

Comment: But if g() is a constant, it is not strictly monotone.

Comment: What have you tried? Suggestion: start with simple cases such as $X$ with possible values $0$ and $1$, with probability $p$ and $1-p$ (Bernoulli distributed). Write $\text{cov}(X,Y)=0$ and you will find that either $g(1)=g(0)$ or $(p=0 \text{ or } p=1)$. You may then move to an $X$ with three possible values and repeat the process, what do you find?

Comment: What is g and $Y$?

Comment: If $X$ is a Bernoulli random variable, let $g$ be a map from $(0,1)$ to $\bigg(g(0),g(1)\bigg)$ and $Y=g(X)$. Compute $\mathbb{E}(X)$, $\mathbb{E}(Y)$, and $\mathbb{E}(XY)$. Write $\mathbb{E}(XY)=\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$, what do you find? What does that tell you about $g(0)$ and $g(1)$?